# Dyncamically loading HTML, JS etc. files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, single-page-application

I am trying to implement a SPA (single page application) without using any framework. I figured that I need to first download all my application resources (HTML, JS, CSS etc.) on my first page load and then use them later.

Now, since I have to pre-load resource and use it later, so I think I have 2 options:

- **Option 1**: Download them using "script" or "link" tag etc. and then refer the downloaded resource later.
- **Option 2**: Download then using `xhr` or `jquery.get()`, put them in a global variable and then use those global variables later.

**Problems with options 1:**

1. First and biggest challenge is how do I refer the downloaded resource later. Lets say I have somehow downloaded all my HTML, JS etc. but later, dynamically, **how will I refer or read or load them later**? I will read it from cache? But what if user has disabled caching of resources?
2. I know I can download JS files using `<script>` tag but **how do I download HTML resource dynamically?** I know some templating engine which can download but I do not want to use any external library.

**Problems with options 2:**

I could pretty much achieve this except below issues:

- I downloaded my resources using `jquery.get` but since I wanted to refer them before DOM rendering so I couldn't use asynchronous mode. I had to download them synchronously. But then there is warning from XHR that synchronous downloading is deprecated. So, **then how I can download a application resource synchronously?**
- I have to keep the content of downloaded resource in a global variable. So, I am **worried that will it be a bad idea because it will consume my browser memory**? How does the frameworks like Backbone.js or AngularJS does it?

Answer (score 1):

Problems with options 1:

- > First and biggest challenge is how do I refer the downloaded resource
  >   later. Lets say I have somehow downloaded all my HTML, JS etc. but
  >   later, dynamically, how will I refer or read or load them later? I
  >   will read it from cache? But what if user has disabled caching of
  >   resources?

First of all, you can't directly download HTML using `<script>` or `<link>` tags as far as I know.

You can download scripts and css, the scripts will be compiled and executed once downloaded, and CSS will be applied to the web page. There is no need to *refer* to them later.

- > I know I can download JS files using `<script>` tag but how do I
  >   download HTML resource dynamically? I know some templating engine
  >   which can download but I do not want to use any external library.

In the above bullet you stated you **can** download HTML using `<script>` tags and now you're saying you can't in the very next bullet of same option. This is already answered, You can't.

Problems with options 2:

I could pretty much achieve this except below issues:

- > I downloaded my resources using jquery.get but since I wanted to
  >   refer them before DOM rendering so I couldn't use asynchronous mode.
  >   I had to download them synchronously. But then there is warning from
  >   XHR that synchronous downloading is deprecated. So, then how I can
  >   download a application resource synchronously?

*"since I wanted to
   refer them before DOM rendering"* - consider DOM rendering is the process of downloading and processing the **mandatory** resources - resources that is needed to present the initial state, and load the resources that is going to be needed later. These will be downloaded by browser (think of the index.html and the `<script>` and `<link>` tag resources in it)

- > I have to keep the content of downloaded resource in a global
  >   variable. So, I am worried that will it be a bad idea because it will
  >   consume my browser memory? How does the frameworks like Backbone.js
  >   or AngularJS does it?

There are techniques like name spacing, IIFE etc used to avoid global variables. And regarding memory, download the extra resources **after** the document is ready, when required. You wouldn't need any **extra** resources before document is ready.

Angular has some sort of optional cache, I haven't came across anything like that in backbone.

---

To conclude, simply load JS and CSS resources that are mandatory using `<script>` and `<link>` tags in index.html. And load any other resources required afterwards using AJAX, you wouldn't need to refer to JS or CSS since that is processed by the browser when injected via `<script>` and `<link>` tags. You can keep a reference to HTML strings simply using variables like `var myHTML= ajaxResponse`.

With all that said, look into libraries like requireJS, lazyload etc that already handles stuff like these.

Comment: For #1.1, that's why I used "somehow downloaded" because my emphasis was on the question that how can I read or load the resource back from the cache? For #1.2, this is a different question, and I guess I know some way - using XHR I can download but it downloads asynchronously and I want to download it synchronously. I couldn't find anything reliable till now for this. For #2.1, my question is specifically about how to download resource synchronously, XHR has deprecated synchronous calls so I do not want to use it.

Comment: For #2.2, IIFE is certainly not what I am looking for and namespace and all will still has to hold the string/content of the resource somewhere - either it will keep in global variable which means memory or somewhere. So, I want to know what the frameworks like Banckbone.js does, do they keep in memory/global variable or how they do it? And if I keep in memory then does it a bad idea? I think no, because even after I download a JS file I can refer the content of it anytime, which means it is loaded in memory for access, right?

Comment: *"I want to download it synchronously."* -why? If you want to refer to something later, you should keep it in memory. That's what all frameworks will do. Cache is a more expensive memory afterall. There is no magic... the variables, objects etc created by the jscode is held in execution environment, not the code itself.

Comment: Synchronously because I want to ensure DOM is not rendered until I hv downloaded all my application resources. You mean it is ok to keep the content of a JS file or HTML file in a global variable? By cache you mean HTTP cache??

Comment: *" I want to ensure DOM is not rendered until I hv downloaded all my application resources"* - Well then don't have anything in dom? or just use css to hide whatever is in DOM until things are downloaded? There is no need to block the browsers main thread while you download stuff. There is no use in making requests synchronous, just download them asynchronously and do whatever you want when it's downloaded. I don't see any point in blocking the browsers main thread with synchronous requests and that's why it's deprecated. Maybe you should look into asynchronous programming..?

Comment: Yes, I do know that. Lets say for some reason, may be I want to provide the users of my framework with an option to download sync and async. This is not my concern - sync v/s async .. My concern is how? And other questions I posted ..

Comment: @hagrawal *"an option to download sync and async"* - synchronous requests are deprecated so users won't ask for this. If they ask tell them it's deprecated. Rest of the questions are already answered as far as I can see... serve initial html via `index.html`, load  js and css required initially  using `<script>`, `<link>` tags in it, have the script for loading resources required later among those download initially via `<script>` tags. For more info, look into the source code of the libraries i mentioned, I can't spent anymore time following this

Comment: Thank you for your inputs and time so far.